# Stored procedure to build new queries and a cursor to help execute them - SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to build a stored procedure that takes in values of

- @field_name
- @some_rule
- @from_table
- @to_table

and builds up a query. Below is the code from my Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spBuildQuery
@field_name nvarchar(max), -- Will take field name as input
@some_rule  nvarchar(max), -- Will take Some rule as a command/input from user
@from_table nvarchar(max), --to take value of table from which value to be taken
@to_table nvarchar(max), --Table where the results should be stored
@final_query nvarchar(max) OUTPUT --Output of final query
AS
IF @some_rule = 'Remove blank rows'
BEGIN
    SELECT @final_query = 'SELECT * into temp1 FROM '+@from_table + ' WHERE '+ @field_name+ ' IS NOT NULL'
END
ELSE IF @some_rule = 'Rule2'
BEGIN
    SELECT @final_query = 'SELECT * into temp1 FROM'+ @from_table + 'WHERE '+ @field_name+ ' IS RULE2'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT @final_query = 'Missing Value(s)'
END


--Executing the query by parsing @final_query value into @query and priting it.
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
EXECUTE spBuildQuery 'A Field', 'Rule2', 'Table 1', @query OUTPUT
PRINT @query
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

My intention is to build queries based on user input like: Rules the user wants to implement what field should the rules be applied to and then display the result of that query onto a table, then that Table gets overwritten as new queries are developed. This is my intention, as another approach I was thinking is to save the built up queries into a table column and execute each query line by line using a cursor.

How can I:

a) store the built up queries into a new TEMP table?
b) execute each query using the Cursor (or any other efficient way)?

Comment: Are yo using MySQL or SQL-Server? Please use just the correct tag.

Comment: And **PLEASE** quote your dynamic objects, and (even better) do some validation on them. If this is SQL Server, I would hate for someone to pass the value `sys.tables; USE master; CREATE LOGIN NewSA WITH PASSWORD = ''123'', CHECK_POLICY = FALSE; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER NewSA;--'` for your parameter `@from_table`. :)

Comment: There are several issues here. You are doing a select into. This means if you run this more than once it will fail because the table already exists. And the sql injection vulnerability here is staggering.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate your goals a bit more here as well. This seems to most definitely be an xy question; I can't see any reason why a `CURSOR` is needed, Also, why is the value of `@query` an `OUTPUT` parameter? Are you doing something with it afterwards? You're already executing it, so I can't find of a good reason why.

Comment: @Barmar I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for your comments. My intention is to build queries based on user input like: Rules the user wants to implement what field should the rules be applied to and then display the result of that query onto a table, then that Table gets overwritten as new queries are developed. This is my intention, as another approach I was thinking is to save the built up queries into a table column and execute each query line by line using a cursor.